# WSO2 DSS Complex input

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server

We are trying to build a data service that take three kind of filters and run a union query to get the metadata based on the passed filters.

The three kind of filters are made of complex data types, when we checked the WSO2 DSS we were not able to do an input mapping for complex types, is that not feasible?

We are trying to get all metadata with one shot though we are getting different inputs and we can't do it scalar as for example all metadata objects has name column.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid, WSO2 DSS at the moment, does not support complex input types. But we are planning on introducing this in the next DSS 4.0.0 version. There, you would be able to pass in a complex input, and also execute multiple queries in a single operation.

Cheers,
Anjana.

Comment: Thanks, When is the plan date for WSO2 DSS 4.0.0?